# SQL Server Management Studio - Column Constraint to Text Options

Tags: sql-server, constraints

I have a simple SQL Server Management Studio database that has a few tables. In each table there are a few columns. Certain columns I would like a constraint that would only allow a value that is predefined in the constraint.

For example, one column is named Valid (data type = nchar(10)) and the only inputs I allow are No and Yes. I was able to make this work:

```
Valid IS ('No', 'Yes')
```

SQL Server Management Studio converted it to:

```
([Valid]='No' OR [Valid]='Yes')
```

So, that works and I tested it. I try this with another few columns in other tables and nothing works. I did not paste code to avoid hidden characters. I change datatype to text, ntext, and they still don't work.

I would like something like this to work (does not currently using either syntax example above):

```
([Location]='Outside' OR [Location]='Inside' OR [Location]='Around Building')
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: While this doesn't answer the question, if you want a column to hold the values `"Yes"` and `"No"`, I'd highly suggest using a `bit` column with a `NOT NULL` constraint over an `nchar` or similar.

Comment: Here is a [reference link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) about `BIT` datatype

Comment: Use T-SQL instead of SSMS. The SSMS designers are not the best and do things behind your back.

Answer (score 0):

Create or alter table with TSQL, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    bar NCHAR(10) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CK_foo_bar CHECK (bar IN (N'No', N'Yes'))
)
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE foo WITH CHECK ADD 
   CONSTRAINT CK_foo_bar CHECK (bar IN (N'No', N'Yes'))
```

or in constraint:

```
([bar]=N'Yes' OR [bar]=N'No')
```

Comment: If I would like a column to only accept values such as 'Inside', 'Outside', 'or 'Around Building', would that work in similar fashion for in constraint? Thanks.

Comment: This format in the Check Constraint Expression field did not work. Such as: ([Location]=N'Outside' OR [Location]=N'Inside' OR [Location]=N'Around Building')